# What is the time complexity of this function using a built-in function?

Tags: python, time-complexity

Assume you have the following `compute` function, using python built-in `sum` function:

```
def compute(a_list):
    for i in range(0, n):                        #Line 1
        number = sum(a_list[0:i + 1])/(i+1)      #Line 2
    return number
```

What would the time-complexity for something like this look like?

`Line 1` is executed n number of times, but `Line 2`, having the built-in `sum` function (O(n)), would it execute n^2  number of times? Therefore the algorithm would be O(n^2).

For each iteration of i, `Line 2` is executed 1 + 2 + 3 + ... + n-2 + n-1 + n. The sum of these terms is

[image]

Is this correct?

Comment: It is correct. It's O(n^2)

Comment: where does `n` come from?  I'd guess either `n = len(a_list)` or `def compute(a_list, n)`…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say that line 1 is executed once, and this causes line 2 to be executed `n` times.  the list subscript is O(n), and the `sum` is also O(n).  division, addition and assignment are all O(1).

`compute` is therefore O(N^2) as the largest terms are evaluating an O(n) operation O(n) times.

note that, as written, it discards all intermediate results, so it could be rewritten as:

```
def compute(a_list):
    return sum(a_list[0:n])/n
```

which would be O(n).

Comment: your "rewritten" part uses `n` => NameError

Comment: @PatrickArtner yup, OP also has this…  they didn't say where `n` is coming from!